# keyboard keys, swapped or not registered

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Just installed Ubuntu to my laptop, when i noticed the backspace button not working.

looking into it I found there are 2 different problems.

1. some of the keys values (not sure what to call it) are swapped.
   using "xve -event keyboard" i found that the backspace button is mapped to the pause button, and that the "-" above the numb pad is mapped to the backspace.[screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILSU0.png)
2. some of the buttons do nothing?
   still with "xve -event keyboard" running, pressing 0,",",3,6,9,*,+ on the numb pad doesn't register, simply nothing appears in the terminal.

I'm not sure how to fix either problem since I'm still somewhat new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Just a guess: a hardware failure in one of the keyboard controller lines. I had some old keyboards that had a defect (which exhibited a similar problem) in one of the parallel line-contacts *before* the microcontroller that passes the key-press-info to the computer via USB. In case of a laptop, this refers to *one line of* [a broken keyboard connector](https://www.laptoprepair101.com/fix-broken-keyboard-connector-on-laptop-motherboard/).